# How to change Roundcube Objects?

Tags: php, roundcube

I'm trying to change the title of my webpages on my roundcube email server but I don't know how or where to alter the roundcube object pagetitle.

```
<title><roundcube:object name="pagetitle" /></title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for (roundcube root)/program/localization/(then the language you choose)/labels.inc

More specifically the pagetitle uses the $config['product_name'] on the config.inc.php in the config folder

Comment: Got it. Added $config['product_name'] to the config.inc.php file

Answer (score 1):

short simple answer : /etc/roundcube/config.inc.php

edit this attribute:
original..
$rcmail_config['product_name'] = 'Roundcube Webmail';

change to..
$rcmail_config['product_name'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Ref : https://vvcares.com/blog/2020/02/how-to-change-roundcube-webmail-title-login-details

Answer (score 0):

or this: */opt/www/roundcubemail/config/defaults.inc.php*

then search for 'product_name'